# Passing in additional variable for Async completed eventhandler

Tags: c#, geocoding

```
private void GeoCode_Method1(string myaddress, int waypointIndex, string callingUser)
{          
    GCService.GeocodeCompleted += new EventHandler<NSpace.GCService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs>(GeoCode_Method1_GeocodeCompleted);
    GCService.GeocodeAsync(request, waypointIndex);
}

void GeoCode_Method1_GeocodeCompleted(object sender, NSpace.GCService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
   //***QUESTION: how do I access variable "callinguser" from GeoCode_Method1 in this method??
}
```

When I call into GeoCode_Method1 I send in "callinguser" string variable, and i would like to access this in GeoCode_Method1_GeocodeCompleted (triggered when the async GeoCodingAsync call is done).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by using a C# lambda expression as the event handler.  This lambda expression can then call into the `GeoCode_Method1_GeocodeCompleted` method and pass along the `callinguser` parameter.

```
GCService.GeocodeCompleted += 
  (sender, e) => GeoCode_Method1_GeocodeCompleted(callinguser, sender, e);
GCService.GeocodeAsync(request, waypointIndex); 

void GeoCode_Method1_GeocodeCompleted(
  string callingUser, 
  object sender, 
  Space.GCService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs e)  { 
     //***QUESTION: how do i access variable "callinguser" from GeoCode_Method1 in this method?? 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the GCService would have a way of handling that for you (it should if it properly followed the Async event pattern), but if it doesn't there is a way using C# closures, though it's a little complicated.

You'd do it as shown below - in my sample I've shown how you can make sure that the GeocodeCompleted event handler gets unsubscribed when the event is completed.

```
private void GeoCode_Method1(string myaddress, int waypointIndex, string callingUser)
{    
     // declare the eventHandler before assignment so that it's accessible in the
     // lambda function      
     EventHandler<NSpace.GCService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs> eventHandler = null;
     eventHandler = (sender, eventArgs) => HandleGeocodeCompleted(sender, eventArgs, callingUser, eventHandler);
     GCService.GeocodeCompleted += eventHandler;
     GCService.GeocodeAsync(request, waypointIndex);
 }

 void HandleGeocodeCompleted(object sender, NSpace.GCService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs e, string callingUser, EventHandler<NSpace.GCService.GeocodeCompletedEventArgs> eventHandler) 
 {
     GCService.GeocodeCompleted -= eventHandler;
     // use callingUser here
 }
```

Comment: Because if you don't the compiler would give you an error at line 6,  Use of unassigned local variable 'eventHandler '

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
private void GeoCode_Method1(string myaddress, int waypointIndex, string callingUser)
{          
    GCService.GeocodeCompleted += (sender, e) => {
        MessageBox.Show(callingUser);
    };
    GCService.GeocodeAsync(request, waypointIndex);
}
```

The lambda expression can access all of the outer methods variables and parameters.  (This is called a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29))

The lambda expression's `sender` and `e` parameters are implicitly typed based on the delegate type it's being used as.